# How to call middle-ware on request and sending response in Node.js

Tags: node.js, express, middleware, interceptor

I need to build a middleware which will intercept the request and add some headers. And before sending the response, need to handle some logic. How can I achieve this?
Below piece of code is getting executed only once.

```
    var express = require('express');
    var http = require('http');
    var app = express();
    app.use(function (req, res, next) {
        console.log(req.requestTime);
        if (!req.requestTime) {
            console.log("Setting!!!")
            req.requestTime = new Date();
            next();
        } else {
            var oldSend = res.send;
            res.send = function (data) {
                console.log("Tracker", res.status);
                console.log(req.requestTime);
                oldSend.apply(res, arguments);
            }
            next();
        }
    })
    const router = express.Router();
    router.get('/', (req, res) => {
        res.status(200).send();
    })

    app.use(router);
    var server = http.createServer(app);

    server.listen(3000);
```

Comment: What is your specific question about the code you show or what is the problem with the code you already have?  It's not clear to me what question you're really asking for help with.  FYI, `res.send()` is not the only way to send a response.  There's also `res.sendStatus()`, `res.json()`, etc...  Perhaps you should listen for the [`finish` event](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_event_finish) on the `res` object rather than overriding one way that the response can be sent.

Comment: When the new request comes, middleware should execute the if condition. Before sending the response back to the user, else block should get executed.
I'm trying to get achieve this behaviour.

Comment: And, what's wrong with the code you already show?  Are you installing it as the first middleware?  If so, show us that code.  If not, that's your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a problem.  There's a new `req` object for every request.  So, when a new request comes in, your middleware is called and there's no `req.requestTime` so the code goes into the first branch of the `if`.  The code NEVER goes into the `else` branch and thus you never hook `res.send` the way you want.

I think you probably want this:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    if (!req.requestTime) {
        console.log("Setting!!!")
        req.requestTime = new Date();
        var oldSend = res.send;
        res.send = function (data) {
            console.log("Tracker", res.statusCode);
            console.log(req.requestTime);
            oldSend.apply(res, arguments);
        }
        next();
    }
});
```

And, you probably don't even need the `if (!req.requestTime)` because this middleware gets called only once per request and no request starts with a `.requestTime` property.

As I said in my comments, it is probably better to listen for the `finish` event on the response object than it is to monkey patch just `res.send()` since there are several other functions that can send a response too.

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    console.log("Setting!!!")
    req.requestTime = new Date();
    res.on('finish', () => {
        console.log("Tracker", res.statusCode);
        console.log(req.requestTime);
    });
    next();
});
```

Comment: `res.on('finish', () => {
            console.log("Tracker", res.statusCode);
            console.log(req.requestTime);
        });` this worked as you mentioned. Thank you!!!

Comment: The original `res.send()` approach can be used for `res.sendStatus()`, `res.json()` and `res.jsonp()` responses because they use `res.send()` internally. This hasn't changed since implementation but use at your own risk.
https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/response.js